WebApplicationFactory for integration test, the service collection cannot be modified because it is read-only
I'm trying to learn how to create integration tests, but when replacing the DbContext from dev db with one from Testcontainers, I'm running into the following error:

The service collection cannot be modified because it is read-only

The tests still run, but points to the dev db configured in my api, and not to the disposable container from Testcontainer.
What am I missing?
Here is my ApplicationFactory with offending line:
    public class ToDoApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
    {
        private readonly MsSqlContainer _msSqlContainer;

        public ToDoApplicationFactory()
        {
            _msSqlContainer = new MsSqlBuilder()
                //.WithPassword("<ommited>")
                .Build();
        }

        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices(async services =>
            {
                await _msSqlContainer.StartAsync();

                var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

                // Remove the existing DbContext registration
                var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                    d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<ToDoDbContext>));

                if (descriptor != null)
                {
                    services.Remove(descriptor); // OFFENDING LINE HERE
                }

                var connectionString = _msSqlContainer.GetConnectionString();

                services.AddDbContext<ToDoDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
                });

                var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

                using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
                {
                    var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                    var db = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ToDoDbContext>();
                    db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                    db.Database.EnsureCreated();
                }
            });
        }

        public override async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        {
            await _msSqlContainer.DisposeAsync();
            await base.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }

Here is my startup class:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(Application.Assembly));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ToDoDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapPost("/api/todos/", async ([FromBody]AddToDoCommand command, [FromServices]ISender sender, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
{
    var id = await sender.Send(command, cancellationToken);
    return Results.CreatedAtRoute("GetToDo", new { id });
})
.WithName("CreateToDo")
.WithOpenApi()
.WithDescription("Create a new ToDo");

app.MapGet("/api/todos/{id}", async (int id, [FromServices]ISender sender, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
{
    return await sender.Send(new GetToDoQuery { Id = id }, cancellationToken);
})
.WithName("GetToDo")
.WithOpenApi()
.WithDescription("Get a single ToDo");

app.Run();

public partial class Program { }

And here is my test class:
public class ToDoTests : IClassFixture<ToDoApplicationFactory<Program>>
{
    const string _url = "api/todos";
    private readonly ToDoApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public ToDoTests(ToDoApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
         _client = factory.CreateClient();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> AddToDoCommandGenerator()
    {
        var faker = new Faker<AddToDoCommand>()
            .RuleFor(x => x.Name, f => f.Lorem.Sentence())
            .RuleFor(x => x.Body, f => f.Lorem.Text());

        return faker.Generate(5).Select(x => new object[] { x });
    }

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(AddToDoCommandGenerator))]
    public async Task CanCreateToDo(AddToDoCommand command)
    {
        var response = await _client.PostAsync(_url,
            new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(command), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.Created, response.StatusCode);
    }
}

